# How do I replace the pin on a tub rocker

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

My tub rocker arm split in half, as the rightmost pin/rivet broke.

Is there any way to fix apart from buying a new assembly?

I've never seen a brass rivet/pin available for sale.

[image: tub rocker arm]

Comment: You either shop in the wrong places, or you don't know where to look. Hardware store MIGHT have them in the bins, somewhere - hobby shop almost certainly will - and the internet will surely have them, though you might need to buy 100 (but they won't cost all that much.) You could also make a piece of copper wire work with a little hammering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecnerwal had the correct idea.

I cut off a piece of 10 AWG copper wire, fitted it it through the empty hole, and used a vise to bend it and mushroom the ends.